# Is it halal to select an exchange rate to benefit my salary?

Tags: halal-haram, money

I am working in a company where I need to submit the daily expense bills in the system for my salary.

My company has fixed my salary (e.g. 10000 Yen/month) and they says that my bills should not exceed the above amount.  If my bills amount to less than that then it is OK.  If not, then I am unable to get my complete salary.

As the billing currency is different and salary deposit currency is different, the system provides three exchange rates, upper rate, mid rate, and lower exchange rate. Will it be OK if I select the upper exchange rate? Or will it be considered as haram, because due to change in rates the salary changes?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is exchange rate for? And why are YOU defining it. Shouldn't the system know the exchange rate or it should have been defined for the day by some supervisor?

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with money like a bank it is haram but if you are just getting a pay rise or getting more momey
 (which I think your saying)
It is completely halal